# Copy and paste ascending cells in data validation

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown, copy-paste

I'm currently setting up a dependent drop down & I've now got it working. The relevant drop-down is in cells L9:L65 with the data for the drop-down being provided in A68:Z68 through to A121:Z121 via the following formula

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF('390'!J9:J65="Livery", TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Operators!$C$2:C, Operators!$C$2:C<>"")), IF('390'!J9:J65="Operator", TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Operators!$B$2:B, Operators!$B$2:B<>"")), ))))`

In cell L9 I've set the following data validation as a list from a range

`A68:Z68`

Which works perfectly. However, when I copy and paste the other cells in the L column all cells relate to A68:Z68 instead of running in ascending order meaning I've just had to manually amend the data validation in L10:L65 to ensure it fetched the correct data and it nearly sent me mad. Considering some of my sheets will incorporate over 200 rows doing this manually is going to prove tedious and time-consuming so I'm hoping someone can show me a way to quickly get each cell corresponding to the correct row without manual intervention?

Comment: You can't make dynamic data validation rules with formulas. You can use the DataValidationBuilder class in Google Apps Script to build rules dynamically [More details](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by standard means (eg. without using a script), this is possible to achieve only manually setting it up row by row (cell by cell) for the whole range.

http://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/google-sheets-apps-script-dynamic-dependent-dropdown-data-validation-lists/